# How to display content based on post author's user role?

Tags: php, wordpress

Most of the code I can find are about specific content being showed to the logged in user based on their role.

I want to do the opposite.

This is basically what I want to do:

If author has "Subscriber" role, show some html A. If author has "Customer" role, show html B.

I think this should be possible but I am not sure where to begin.

Here's the snippet I am using but not working so might have error somewhere?

```
 <?php $current_author_roles = get_the_author_meta('roles');?>
 <?php if ( in_array('Customer', $current_author_roles) ) { ?>
   //do something
 <?php } else { ?>
   //do something else  
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is where you need to use what is called a conditional statement. `if(condition){...}else{...}`

Comment: Maybe You should tell us more about what You have done to this moment?

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional. For example:

```
$current_author_roles = get_the_author_meta('roles');
if ( in_array('Customer', $current_author_roles) ) {
    // do something
}
```

You can read more about [get_the_author_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta).

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing the code.  I've made a snippet according to your suggestion and edited my question.  Please check if there's an error as it's not working.